# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to execute below command on Hadoop

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

but it is returing with the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.  Program will exit.
```

I have tried updating the java but it is still giving me the same error.

**Note:** The same command is working on the other nodes but not on 2 for the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is not working because it is pointing to the newer version of hadoop jars avilable on the nodes instead of the hadoop jars of installed version

It was pointing to jars placed in

```
/usr/lib/hadoop
```

Then i tried to execute it from the installation directory as below

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the JDK to version 1.7. Perhaps, you have updated JRE not JDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the CDH, you may need change the java version to jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera. After I changed the JAVA_HOME from `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31` to `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera`, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

You need Java 7 (or higher) to run this.
See: https://www.java.com/de/download/faq/java_7.xml

If you already installed Java 7 (or higher) then execute it with:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\<Java Version (jre7/jre8>\bin\java.exe -jar <Path To .Jar>
```